# Accessing the properties of an object without knowing the names of those properties not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have index.php with:

These php lines

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM voedingsmiddelen";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

On the same page i have this code where extract data from table and put it in an array.

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode( mysqli_fetch_all( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) ?>;
var arraytype = typeof array;
alert('type: '+arraytype);

var i=0;
for(key in array) {
    alert('for loop working');
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = data[key];
        alert(value);
    } else {
        alert('has no property');
    }
}
```

i only get one alert saying 'type: object'. So the "gettype" is working. But the other alerts are not displaying. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try key of array maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean value indicating whether the object on which you are calling it has a property with the name of the argument [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).So try this

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    alert('for loop working');
    if(array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var value = i;
        alert(value);
    } else {
        alert('has no property');
    }
}
```

or in your case this:

```
var i=0;
for(key in array) {
    alert('for loop working');
    if(array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = key;
        alert(value);
    } else {
        alert('has no property');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check if array is not empty. When you remove php code and put raw array:

```
var array = ["a", "a"];
```

Code seems to be working, at least second alert is displaying. However, `data[key]` is not defined. Should be `array[key]` ?